# How to stop the select box from being blocked as a pop-up bit Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: jquery, xhtml, popup, blocking

I'm working on a website where if I click on a normal select box it's blocked as a popup by IE8. What?! Is there something I'm doing? Is there any way around this?

I am using a few jQuery plugins but nothing that effects those select boxes. Would the jQuery Form plugin do this?

Comment: Do you have a sample online somewhere?

Comment: It's just a normal select element inside a form. You can see an example of one here:

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_option

I just did a test, the same thing happens when you click the select box on this page. IE7 and IE8 say it is a popup.

Also, there are no javascript actions being applied to the select box on my site. I can't send a link because it's client-work and it's not released yet. This came up while browser testing in lesser browsers.

Comment: The site you linked works fine for me in IE8 on WinXP SP3. Are you sure you don't have any adblockers, firewalls, or malware on your machine tampering with the page and IE?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [known bug](http://www.webmasterworld.com/html/3888881.htm) introduced by running some versions of software which install multiple versions of IE simultaneously.

Upgrade.

Better yet, switch to using VMs to test in older versions of IE. That will give you a safer environment that better reflects reality.

Comment: This collection of multiple IE versions has fixed this bug:

http://finalbuilds.edskes.net/iecollection.htm


It seems to be safe to install directly over MultipleIEs

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that your onclick -- or whatever event is triggered -- is trying to create a new window or something like that.

Comment: There is no onclick associated with that select box element.